# Probability weather impacts outdoor event

Tags: probability

Need some help with a probability scenario. I'm a photographer that conducts outdoor photo shoots. I have two models of cameras that require different environmental conditions to operate. I have 24 outdoor shoots lined up for the year; 12 with each model of camera.

There is a 25% chance Camera A will NOT be able to operate on any given day and a 12% chance Camera B will NOT be able to operate.

Additionally, on any given day, there's a 5% chance lightning will block me from taking photographs, a 10% chance rain will prevent and a 1% chance wildfires will prevent.

How many calendar days do I need to book to ensure I get my 24 full days of photographs?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What do you consider a "full day" of photographs? When both cameras are working, or when at least one camera is working?

Comment: Do you want lightning, rain, and wildfires to be considered independent events, even though that is unrealistic (e.g. lightning is often accompanied by rain, rain prevents forest fires, and lightning without rain can cause a forest fire)?

Comment: @MatthewPilling - Only one camera needs to be operable to conduct a photo shoot.

Comment: @user2661923 - yes they weather should be considered independent events, basically what are the chances at least one of these events occur. I'm calculating 15.355% probability, but that's the easy part of this equation.

Comment: See my answer, which may not be appropriate, depending on your needs.  The answer requires that you set *confidence levels* for each camera and then manually (or with software) compute the minimum values of $n$ and $m$ to achieve these confidence levels.

Comment: Are you *actually* a photographer, or are you trying to disguise what sounds to me like a homework problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yes they weather should be considered independent events, basically what are the chances at least one of these events occur. I'm calculating 15.355% probability, but that's the easy part of this equation.

The OP (i.e. original poster) did correctly calculate that 
$(1 - 0.05)(1 - 0.01)(1 - 0.10) = (1 - 0.15355)$.

Further, deciding the next step is tricky.  Therefore, I am interpreting the OP's question + comment as constituting work shown; if I get downvoted, so be it.

Based on the (unrealistic) premise that lightning, rain, and wildfires are independent events, the chance of all of these factors **not** being relevant on a given day are $(0.84645).$

The next step is to consider each camera separately, and determine the chance of being able to take pictures with that camera on a given day.  Before I proceed, there is a subtlety that needs discussion.

If the use of Camera A on (for example) June 1 is feasible, then that drastically affects whether Camera B can also be used on June 1.  This is because for Camera A to be usable on June 1, the *non-events* of no lightning, no rain, and no  brushfires must have all occurred.  These *non-events* impact whether Camera B is usable.

Now, we come to a somewhat tricky interpretation issue, of the problem:

> Need some help with a probability scenario. I'm a photographer that conducts outdoor photo shoots. I have two models of cameras that require different environmental conditions to operate. I have 24 outdoor shoots lined up for the year; 12 with each model of camera.

> How many calendar days do I need to book to ensure I get my 24 full days of photographs?

From the above excerpts of the question, I infer that the OP does not intend to use Camera A and Camera B on the same day. Beyond that, there is a hidden question: what happens if the weather is agreeable on June 1, the OP goes to site A-1 on the morning of June 1 to use Camera A, and Camera A malfunctions?
Does the OP then go to site B-1 (still) on June 1, taking advantage of the agreeable weather, to attempt to use Camera B.

For simplicity, I will assume not.  One justification is that agreeable weather at site A-1 may not imply agreeable weather at site B-1.  Another justification is that preparation for the use of Camera A at site A-1 coupled with similar preparation at Site B-1 is too time consuming for one day.  However, these are all **my excuses**.  I am simplifying, only to ease the analysis in this answer.

The combined chance that Camera A proves to be usable on a given day is

$$P_{A} = (1 -  0.25)(1 - 0.15355) = 0.6348375.$$

Similarly

$$P_{B} = (1 -  0.12)(1 - 0.15355) = 0.744876.$$

$$\text{Let }~Q_A = 1 - P_A ~~\text{and} ~~\text{let} ~Q_B = 1 - P_B.$$

Suppose that $n$ days ($n \geq 12$) are booked for Camera $A$.  The chance of getting exactly $k$ successful days are

$\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}(P_A)^k (Q_A)^{n-k}.$

This means that the chance of getting **at least** $(12)$ successful days are

$$T_A(n) = \sum_{k=12}^n \binom{n}{k}(P_A)^k (Q_A)^{n-k}.\tag1$$

The OP will have to **arbitrarily** choose a confidence level (e.g. 99%).  Once, that is done, then the OP will have to manually (or programmatically, with software) find the smallest positive integer $n$, such that $T_A(n) \geq (0.99).$

There is a moderate simplification to equation 1 above.  The OP wants $[1 - T_A(n)] \leq (0.01).$  Therefore, the OP can use the equation:

$$[1 - T_A(n)] = \sum_{k=0}^{11} \binom{n}{k}(P_A)^k (Q_A)^{n-k}.\tag2$$

Under the (significantly) simplifying assumption (already discussed), the analysis around Camera B, and therefore around both Cameras is similar.  Suppose (for example) that the OP wants an **overall** confidence level of $(0.98)$.  You can achieve this by having a confidence level of $(0.99)$ for both Camera A and Camera B.  This is because

$\displaystyle [1 - (0.01)] \times [1 - (0.01)] = 1 - 2(0.01) + (0.01)^2 > [1 - 2(0.01)].$

Assume that the definition of $T_B(m)$ is analogous to the definition of $T_A(n).$  That is:

$$T_B(m) = \sum_{k=12}^m \binom{m}{k}(P_B)^k (Q_B)^{m-k}.\tag3$$

Further assume that the OP accepts a $(0.98)$ overall confidence level, and will achieve this by a $(0.99)$ confidence level for each of Camera A and Camera B.

Then, just as the OP will have to manually or programatically find the smallest positive integer $n$ to accommodate equation (2) above, the OP will also have to similarly find the smallest positive integer $m$ to accommodate equation (4), below:

$$[1 - T_B(m)] = \sum_{k=0}^{11} \binom{m}{k}(P_B)^k (Q_B)^{m-k}.\tag4$$